# Avoid connect 2nd DHCPs on 1 LAN

Tags: dhcp, local-area-network

I have a LAN network using Draytek 2910 with DHCP. The network goes through 20 different rooms. At first everything is working good. Suddendly the network keep losing IP addresses every 30 t0 60 seconds. I suspect that some one connected another router (LAN port) to other end of the network and 2 DHCPs trying to take control of each other. How can we avoid something like this happend again ?

Comment: Ask your network administrator to look into it. What makes you suspect a second DHCP, another IP range being distributed? How do you prevent it? Tell your users to not plug anything into your network?

Comment: http://www.latinsud.com/pub/dhd/dhd.c This tool is a simple DHCP discovery for linux. It may help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure DHCP snooping/filtering on the Switch.

Comment: Your only real option is this really. Does mean you need a decent switch of course...

Comment: True, though you can get some really decent *used* gear if you know what to look for. I just picked up an old ProCurve GL (L3 Modular Switch) with 100x 100Mb ports for <$200 for a low-end office building remodel.

Answer (score 0):

Configure DHCP snooping/filtering on each port except trusted DHCP server on the switch.

Ban users from plugging rogue devices into the network and create consequences for violations.

Setup client (Windows firewall, iptables, etc) firewalls to only accept traffic from the trusted mac address on ports 67/68.

And again: Don't let users plug in rogue devices.